# Center the view in the space it occupies with Linear / Weight

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a linear layout (horizontal) with 5 text views in it.  My goal is to have two of the textviews on the left side of the screen, large space in the middle and then the remaining text views on the right.

Something like this.

[  text  ]  [  text  ]  [        blank        ]  [  text  ]  [ text  ]

ends up like this.

[text  ]  [text  ]  [        blank        ]  [text  ]  [text  ]

I can get this to work with weight, almost.  The problem is that the text view appears left justified within the space it occupies and I am trying to get the text that displays to be centered within the space it occupies.

Is this possible?

Comment: Have you tried `android:textAlignment="center"`? (it requires api 17)

Answer (score 0):

You can try it

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView1"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView2"/>
        <View
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#f00"></View>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView3"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView4"/>
    </LinearLayout>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

android:textAlignment="center" did the job.

Appreciate the example above as well.  Good stuff!

Answer (score 0):

Try as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:weightSum="5">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="text1"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_weight="1"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:text="text2"
    android:layout_weight="1"/>

<Space
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="text1"
    android:layout_weight="1"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="text3"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_weight="0.66"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:text="text4"
    android:layout_weight="0.66"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="text5"
    android:layout_weight="0.66"/>


</LinearLayout>
```

Write android:singleLine="true" if you want your textview to one liner.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this easily with RelativeLayout

> [text1] [text2]       [blank]     [text3] [text4]

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="text1" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tv1"
        android:text="text2" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/tv4"
        android:text="text3" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:text="text4" />
</RelativeLayout>
```